# Powershell strange parameter behaviour

Tags: powershell

To start off, I'm just going to paste the result of `$PSVersionTable.PSVersion` as, apparantly, it shows the version of powershell...

```
You are now entering PowerShell : <name>
PS D:\aDirectory> $PSVersionTable.PSVersion

Major  Minor  Build  Revision
-----  -----  -----  --------
4      0      -1     -1
```

Below I have a function, `DoSomeSqlForMe`, which defines two parameters, `$sql` and `$logFile`.

When function is called, `$sql` is passed into it.  `$logFile` is inherited from a parent script (but may also be passed in).

```
function DoSomeSqlForMe
{
    param
    (
        [string]$sql,
        [string]$logFile
    )

    #Do some stuff with $sql and $logfile
}
```

EDIT - function is being called as below (this is a direct copy + typical of other calls to same function):

```
DoSomeSqlForMe $sql
```

My issue is when `$logFile` is set as a parameter but not passed in when method is called (`$logFile` is still available as an inherited var) I get 
`Exception message : The argument is null or empty.`

However when I simply remove $logFile as a parameter, my log file is filled with what looks to me (uneducated in eastern languages) like Mandarin - `渮浡` repeated over and over again.

Any ideas?

Comment: First of all is the missing comma between $sql and [string] a copy paste error? And can you please show how you call your function?

Comment: Hi rufer7, yes comma was a copy paste error apologies.  Added method call to question.

Comment: You do not pass anything to `$logFile` so it will have default value (not the value from outer scope). BTW you define `DoSomeSqlForMe` but calling `DoSql`.

Comment: Apologies, rufer7 kindly edited for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, that if you don't provide `$logFile` parameter when calling the function (i.e. `DoSomeSqlForMe $arbitrarySql`) by default `$null` gets assigned to `$logFile` parameter. To assign the before defined `$logFile` variable by default to the function parameter you have to adjust your function as follows.

```
function DoSomeSqlForMe
{
    param
    (
        [string]$sql,
        [string]$logFile = $logFile
    )

    #Do some stuff with $sql and $logfile
}
```

However I suggest to instead call your function with two parameters (i.e.  `DoSomeSqlForMe -sql $arbitrarySql -logFile $logFile`)

Comment: This worked, thanks.  This job is currently running every night on a Win2003 server with the code above - and it works.  We are migrating to Win2012 and it doesn't work :)  I guess this could be a powershell version issue?  I do not have access to the old production server to check unfortunately.

Comment: If I do `[string]$logFile = $logFile` it works ok, however as I'm sure you know it limits what can be passed in.  When I pass in `$logFile` I get the lines of mandarin though :(

Comment: What do you mean by "the code above"? The code you provided or mine? 
Concerning limiting I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: The code I provided is currently running in production on a Win2003 server.

Comment: It's possible, that this is a version issue, yes. What about your second comment where you mention some limitations?

Comment: @xeon48 If my answer correctly answered your question please rate it mark it as answer.